# How to add to Text Label For excel Charts using Open xml or EPPLUS

Tags: c#, excel, openxml-sdk, epplus, spreadsheetlight

I am completely new to Excel automation in C#

Actually I am came across  some of API for Excel generation in C# .net  like CLOSED XML , EEPLUS , and  spreadsheetlight  by vincent  ,Open XML by Microsoft , Interop excel by Microsoft

According My Study

CLOSED XML  -- No charts supported

EEPLUS - Charts supported

Spread light- Very easy to use and Charts also supported

Open XML- complex  hard to work

I was completely fine with  Spread light light was good API , but i am not able to find a solution how to add label inside a Chart

I hope any one in stack overflow came across with same problem.

I need to add label like text inside  chart like  for example Company  in chart.

Please let me know how to find solution  any one this Free API

[image: Please find chart info here]

Thanks
Ranjith

Answer (score 3):

You can add at title via Epplus but positioning will require XML editing:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Chart_Manual_Title_Test()
    {
        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37304860/how-to-add-to-text-label-for-excel-charts-using-open-xml-or-epplus
        //Throw in some data
        var datatable = new DataTable("tblData");
        datatable.Columns.AddRange(new[] { new DataColumn("Col1", typeof(int)), new DataColumn("Col2", typeof(int)), new DataColumn("Col3", typeof(object)) });

        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var row = datatable.NewRow();
            row[0] = i;
            row[1] = i * 10;
            row[2] = Path.GetRandomFileName();
            datatable.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        //Create a test file    
        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\Chart_Manual_Title_Test.xlsx");
        if (fileInfo.Exists)
            fileInfo.Delete();

        using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo))
        {
            var workbook = pck.Workbook;
            var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
            worksheet.Cells.LoadFromDataTable(datatable, true);

            var chart = worksheet.Drawings.AddChart("chart test", eChartType.XYScatter);
            var series = chart.Series.Add(worksheet.Cells["B2:B11"], worksheet.Cells["A2:A11"]);

            chart.Title.Text = "XYZ Corp";

            //Add custom layout
            var chartXml = chart.ChartXml;
            var nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(chartXml.NameTable);

            var nsuri = chartXml.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI;
            nsm.AddNamespace("c", nsuri);
            nsm.AddNamespace("a", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main");

            //Set the title overlay
            var overlayNode = chartXml.SelectSingleNode("c:chartSpace/c:chart/c:title/c:overlay", nsm);
            overlayNode.Attributes["val"].Value = "1";

            //Set the font size
            var defRPrNode = chartXml.SelectSingleNode("c:chartSpace/c:chart/c:title/c:tx/c:rich/a:p/a:pPr/a:defRPr", nsm);
            defRPrNode.Attributes["sz"].Value = "1200";

            //Get the title layout and add the manual section
            var layoutNode = chartXml.SelectSingleNode("c:chartSpace/c:chart/c:title/c:layout", nsm);
            var manualLayoutNode = chartXml.CreateElement("c:manualLayout", nsuri);
            layoutNode.AppendChild(manualLayoutNode);

            //Add coordinates
            var xModeNode = chartXml.CreateElement("c:xMode", nsuri);
            var attrib = chartXml.CreateAttribute("val");
            attrib.Value = "edge";
            xModeNode.Attributes.Append(attrib);
            manualLayoutNode.AppendChild(xModeNode);

            var yModeNode = chartXml.CreateElement("c:yMode", nsuri);
            attrib = chartXml.CreateAttribute("val");
            attrib.Value = "edge";
            yModeNode.Attributes.Append(attrib);
            manualLayoutNode.AppendChild(yModeNode);

            var xNode = chartXml.CreateElement("c:x", nsuri);
            attrib = chartXml.CreateAttribute("val");
            attrib.Value = "0.9";
            xNode.Attributes.Append(attrib);
            manualLayoutNode.AppendChild(xNode);

            var yNode = chartXml.CreateElement("c:y", nsuri);
            attrib = chartXml.CreateAttribute("val");
            attrib.Value = "0.95";
            yNode.Attributes.Append(attrib);
            manualLayoutNode.AppendChild(yNode);

            pck.Save();
        }
    }
```

Which gives you this in the output:

[image]

---

### RESPONSE TO COMMENTS

Ok, thats a little tougher.  The right way would be to use a `relSizeAnchor` which can be placed inside the chart and moved/sized with it.  But that you would have to do from scratch (or at best another library).  If you activate a chart in excel and do an Insert > Text Box to see what that looks like.

Another option would be to fake it by using an unused title like say an Axis Title and moving it similar to how I did the chart title.

But the easiest option would be to simply add a shape.  The draw back is if you move the chart it will not move with it:

```
var tb1 = worksheet.Drawings.AddShape("tb1", eShapeStyle.Rect);
tb1.Text = "ABC Company";
tb1.SetPosition(1, 0, 2, 0);
tb1.SetSize(200, 20);
tb1.Font.Color = Color.Black;
tb1.TextAlignment = eTextAlignment.Center;
tb1.Fill.Color = Color.LightYellow;
tb1.Fill.Style = eFillStyle.SolidFill;
tb1.Border.Fill.Color = Color.Red;
```

gives this as the output when combined with above:

[image]

Comment: Ernie sorry , i need chart title also i dont want to loss chart title for that , i need both chart titile and extra textbox

Comment: Please help in find soultion for this using  relSizeAnchor  i need this feature, but i cant go to interoperability :( i dont like that API     as well , i should do it some how in EEPLUS or OPEN XML

Comment: @RanjithMurthy  Look at this: http://www.datypic.com/sc/ooxml/e-cdr_relSizeAnchor-1.html and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff534388%28v=office.12%29.aspx  Also install the Open XML 2.5 SDK from MS.  You will have to insert the XML like I did in my original response.  If you open the xls in 7zip you can check out the chart.xml file to see what it looks like.  Give that a shot and post your code if you are having trouble.

Answer (score 1):

[Essential XlsIO](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/xlsio) can add textboxes to Excel charts.

[Example code](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/XlsIOSample1575938773.zip)

`//Accessing the chart of the worksheet 
            IChartShape shape = workbook.Worksheets[0].Charts[0]; 
            //Adding textbox to chart shape 
            shape.TextBoxes.AddTextBox(1,1, 100,200); 
            //Setting position for textbox 
            shape.TextBoxes[0].Top = 900; 
            shape.TextBoxes[0].Left = 750; 
            //Adding text to textbox 
            shape.TextBoxes[0].Text = "New textbox";`

The whole suite of controls is available for free (commercial applications also) through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) program if you qualify (less than 1 million US Dollars in revenue). The community license is the full product with no limitations or watermarks.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the chart already exists in your template and you are just adding data, then you can read the contents of the box from a cell on the page. Then from C# you just need to write to the cell. This lets you do any formatting or positioning you want in Excel.

Comment: Mr.white I can't do that hard coded way since I have 500charts in one single work book I have around 10 to 15 chart types (bar , line combo , column etc ) so that won't work sorry :( I am stil wait for simple approach to do that in. Open xml it's bit hard

Comment: I am using interoperability com objects now it's working fine but it's bit solve